# certbot installation via salt and a proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, lets-encrypt, salt-stack, certbot

I have a salt state which starts a letsencrypt acme challenge and install the certbot but the whole challenge has to go via a proxy which I also set in the salt state. Could you please confirm that this salt state is working and the acme challenge are done via the proxy?

```
{% set proxy_url = 'http://' %} 

set-proxy:
  environ.setenv:
    - name: set-proxy
    - value:
        http_proxy: {{ proxy_url }}
        https_proxy: {{ proxy_url }}
    - update_minion: True

certbot:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: certbot
    - require:
      - environ: set-proxy

reload-nginx:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl reload nginx.service
    - require:
      - pkg: certbot

<domain>:
  acme.cert:
    - aliases:
      - <domain>
    - email: <mail>
    - webroot: <webroot path>
    - renew: 14
    - fire_event: acme/<domain>
    - onchanges:
      - cmd: reload-nginx
    - require:
      - environ: set-proxy
```

I tried it and it didnt work. Now I'am not sure if it's the firewall or the wrong salt state.

Comment: Your requisites still don't make sense, as noted in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salt state you provided appears to be correctly setting the proxy and installing Certbot before performing the ACME challenge and obtaining the SSL certificate. However, there is an issue with the way you are setting the `proxy_url` variable.

Currently, you have set `proxy_url` as `'http://'`. This will not specify a valid proxy address. You need to provide the complete proxy URL, including the hostname or IP address and the port number if applicable. For example, it should be something like `'http://proxy.example.com:8080'`.

Assuming you provide the correct proxy URL, the state seems to be properly configured to execute the ACME challenge via the proxy. The `environ.setenv` state sets the proxy environment variables, and the subsequent `pkg.installed` state installs Certbot, which depends on the proxy being set correctly.

The `acme.cert` state for your `<domain>` appears to be correctly configured as well. It specifies the necessary parameters for the ACME challenge, such as aliases, email, webroot path, renewal period, and event triggering for certificate changes. It also has a `require` statement to ensure that the proxy environment variables are set before executing the ACME challenge.

The `reload-nginx` state uses the `cmd.run` state to trigger a command for reloading the Nginx service, and it depends on the successful installation of Certbot (`pkg: certbot`).

To confirm if the ACME challenges are being done via the proxy, you can check the logs or debug output of Certbot during the certificate issuance process. Additionally, you can monitor the network traffic on the proxy server to see if there are requests to the Let's Encrypt ACME servers.